# Setting last update time on node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I would like to update `lastUpdate` field in node each time some property is change.

Is there is some general solution for it from Neo4j level or Spring Data?

The problem is that our structure and code exsist and these feature has to be added. We use in application Spring Data (ver. 3.1.1) with Aspects. As I see it now I have to change:

- change behaviour of `save()` method from `GraphRepository`
- change behaviour of  Aspect method `persist()` from node

I wonder if there is some simpler method that these steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`TransactionEventHandler`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html). In your case use the `beforeCommit` method, iterate over the the changed properties in that transaction using [`TransactionData.assignedNodeProperties()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionData.html#assignedNodeProperties()) and set the `lastUpdate` on the given to current timestamp.

TransactionEventHandler are a sharp tool, be very careful to keep the impact as small as possible.

Comment: Thank you - yes it seems that is what I am looking for.

Comment: It was to beautiful to be true ;) - I forget about one - we use REST protocol to connect to Neo4j. And as I see `AbstractRemoteDatabase` not allow to register any handler.

Do you know if it can be handled i some other way?

Comment: You cannot do this remotely. The best practice is creating a KernelExtension that registers the tx handler, Max explains this very well at http://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/

Comment: Wonderful - I've just implement such extension and work like a charm. Thank you.